# Symbian Adobe Reader command line arguments

Tags: pdf, command-line, symbian, acrobat, adobe-reader

What is the correct command line format to have Adobe Reader open up a PDF automatically on a Symbian phone?

For example, to load an image into image viewer it would be: -

Z:\sys\bin\imageviewer.exe -file /E:\Data\image.jpg

I have tried the same for Z:\sys\bin\AdobeReader.exe, however this doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct format to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a PDF file using the platform's default PDF viewer, use e.g. `CDocumentHandler`'s file open functionality or `RApaLsSession::StartDocument()`. Or is there a specific reason for invoking `adobereader.exe` specifically yourself?

Comment: I have a desktop program which connects to the phone via AppTRK. You have to give it an application (for example Z:\sys\bin\AdobeReader.exe), and any command line arguments. The application will then run the command. My aim is to have the handset load Adobe Reader with a PDF file that is on the phone (ie E:\Data\file.pdf). I haven't been able to provide the arguments in the correct format thus far, and was just wondering if anyone knew what the correct format was?

Comment: @Simon: Hmm, a little wierd use case I think :) You can roll a wrapper exe of your own which takes whatever command line arguments you want and then uses `CDocumentHandler` or `RApaLsSession` for launching the viewer.